# Save profile data based on user id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, domdocument

I am working on a profile page where you will be able to edit your profile data like first name, last name, date of birth etc.
The inputs are filled with the right data from the database based on the user id that is stored in a session. The next step is to be able to edit these fields and that they will save in the database row that has the id of the session. I cant make the save work. With the code down below i get an error **Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\dev\www\portfolio\profile.php on line 84** line 84 contains the following code. **VALUES ('$input0101', '$input0102', '$input0103', '$input0104', '$input0105', '$input0106', '$input0107', '$input0108')");** I hope someone can help me :)!

The code that stores the right data in the inputs.

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "portfolio");
    $select_data = mysql_select_db('portfolio', $connect);
    $select_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE `id`='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($fetch=mysql_fetch_assoc($select_data)) {

        $oImgBox = $dom->getElementById('adminProfilePicture');
        $oImg = $dom->createElement('image');
        $oImg->setAttribute('src',$fetch["profilepic"]);
        $oImgBox->appendChild($oImg);

        $oInput = $dom->getElementById('input0101');
        $oInput->setAttribute('value',$fetch["firstname"]);
        $oInput = $dom->getElementById('input0102');
        $oInput->setAttribute('value',$fetch["lastname"]);
        $oInput = $dom->getElementById('input0103');
        $oInput->setAttribute('value',$fetch["dateofbirth"]);
        $oInput = $dom->getElementById('input0104');
        $oInput->setAttribute('value',$fetch["adress"]);
        $oInput = $dom->getElementById('input0105');
        $oInput->setAttribute('value',$fetch["zipcode"]);
        $oInput = $dom->getElementById('input0106');
        $oInput->setAttribute('value',$fetch["city"]);
        $oInput = $dom->getElementById('input0107');
        $oInput->setAttribute('value',$fetch["country"]);
        $oInput = $dom->getElementById('input0108');
        $oInput->setAttribute('value',$fetch["phone"]);
        $oInput = $dom->getElementById('input0201');
        $oInput->setAttribute('value',$fetch["username"]);
        $oInput = $dom->getElementById('input0202');
        $oInput->setAttribute('value',$fetch["password"]);  
    }
```

The code that is suposed to save the changed data in the database.

```
        if (isset($_POST["input0101"])) {
        $id=$_SESSION['id'];
        $input0101 = $_POST['input0101'];
        $input0102 = $_POST['input0102'];
        $input0103 = $_POST['input0103'];
        $input0104 = $_POST['input0104'];
        $input0105 = $_POST['input0105'];
        $input0106 = $_POST['input0106'];
        $input0107 = $_POST['input0107'];
        $input0108 = $_POST['input0108'];
        mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO members WHERE `id`='$id' (firstname, lastname, dateofbirth, adress, zipcode, city, country, phone)
        VALUES ('$input0101', '$input0102', '$input0103', '$input0104', '$input0105', '$input0106', '$input0107', '$input0108')");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a connection with mysql_connect and then passed it to mysqli_query. Notice the **i**.

Google "mysqli for begineers" and "sql injection".

Comment: Yes i saw that xD my bad i changed it but i still get the warning
Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\dev\www\portfolio\profile.php on line 84
and line 84 contains
VALUES ('$input0101', '$input0102', '$input0103', '$input0104', '$input0105', '$input0106', '$input0107', '$input0108')");

Comment: mysql_query gets query as first parameter, than connection. So put $connect as second parameter.

Comment: Ok, i changed it but somehow there doesnt happends anything xD

Comment: I moved the IF statement inside the WHILE now it works thanks for the help!